# SQL Select sum query variable

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
@frst:= (1) 
+   
@scnd:= (2) as 'Total',
@frst as 'Frst',
@scndas 'Scnd'
```

This query returns 3 - 3 - 2 and not 3 - 1 - 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are many flavours of SQL; you should specify the version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is assigning variables in one expression and using the values in another.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`, so this is not safe.

This is explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> As a general rule, other than in `SET` statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> ```
> SET @a = @a + 1;
> ```
>
> For other statements, such as `SELECT`, you might get the results you expect,
>   but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement,
>   you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an
>   assignment second:
>
> ```
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
> ```
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables
>   is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you are doing :

```
SELECT
@frst:= (1) // *1
+   
@scnd:= (2) as 'Total',// *2
@frst as 'Frst',// *3
@scnd as 'Scnd'// *4
```

is like :

```
*1 & *2 => set @frst to 1, set @scnd to 2,add and assign to @frst return as total which is 3 (1 + 2)
*3 => @frst as 'Frst' // return 3 as Frst
*4 => @scnd as 'Scnd' // return 2 as Scnd
```

and your query returns `total` which is equal to 3, `Frst` which is equal to 3 and `Scnd` which is equal to 2
Hope you get it right.